# What is required to reinstall Windows 10 on a replacement computer?

Tags: windows-10, license

I've happily performed the free upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  After July 2016 it is no longer free to upgrade.  I have not been part of the Insider Program at all.

Hypothetically, if my computer were to have a catastrophic failure after July 2016 that required it being replaced entirely, what would I need to have backed up to ensure I could continue to use my existing Windows 10 license rather than buy a new one?  Is there a Product Key I can extract and store in a safe place?

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to extract a product key, though most regular tools haven't done that yet. They give you the windows insider/generic keys instead.

I copied the [script here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/11/12/how-to-find-the-windows-10-product-key-after-an-upgrade.aspx) and it seems to retrive the *real* installation key

Copy and paste this into notepad, and save it as a vbs file, and run it as admin, and it outputs the real key. I haven't had a chance to see if it works on different hardware yet.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

I haven't had a chance to try this on dissimilar hardware though.

Comment: I have my doubts that the key provided would activate on the new hardware.  Technically speaking the free license, is only for the machine you upgraded before July 29th 2016.  You can technically upgrade as many machines with the eligible retail license as you want, provided the previous machine is retired and these machines are activated before July 30th 2016.  **If you live in a country where you get extended rights with regards to your windows license, contact Microsoft, and request they provide you a Windows 10 key that  CAN be transferred per your legal rights outlined in the EULA.**

Comment: Yup, but this is the *actual* key it seems, as opposed to a generic key.

Answer (score 1):

> what would I need to have backed up to ensure I could continue to use my existing Windows 10 license rather than buy a new one? Is there a Product Key I can extract and store in a safe place?

If You used limited time offer free upgrade to Windows 10, You got a license which is linked to Your current hardware. It's upgrade license, which will never expire on Your current hardware, but it cannot be used on any other hardware. For example if free upgrade period expired and Your PC broken, You replace it to new PC and need to buy new Windows 10 license. You cannot use Your old upgrade license on new PC. If Windows 10 detects significant hardware change since upgrade, it will not activate. You cannot use upgrade license legally if You changed hardware such as motherboard and may be system HDD(?).
You don't need to enter product key on current hardware, it should activate automatically after clean reinstall, when connected to Internet. So NO, no product key which can be exported. Just some code for Your hardware which is sent to Windows license center, and will be checked after reinstall. If found, it will activate, if not, go buy new copy of Windows.

If You bought a retail license of Windows 10, You have Your personal serial number which will activate some limited number of times on any hardware. After that number key may be activated by phone. And if You try to activate it too many times, serial may be blocked.